# How to copy NSDate to UIPasteboard?

Tags: ios, copy-paste, uipasteboard

According to the docs I must use

```
- (void)setValue:(id)value forPasteboardType:(NSString *)pasteboardType
```

But I can't find the UTI for NSDate. I want to copy the raw NSDate itself as well as a formatted string representation.

Is there a way to do this other than copying just a string?

Comment: why would you want to add an NSDate to the pasteboard, what is the behavior you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Copy a NSDate, and in some other location paste it back in. Calendaric stuff.

Comment: another location within your application?

Comment: Yes. Just one NSDate to another loc. But I want to keep it generic, so other apps could possibly use that NSDate too.

Comment: did you try using     [[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard] setData: forPasteboardType:]?

Comment: nope, because it's unclear what pasteboard type to set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/UTIRef/Articles/System-DeclaredUniformTypeIdentifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009259-SW1) does seem rather vague on how property list objects such as NSDate objects are to be referenced!

Looking at UTCoreTypes.h in the MobileCoreServices framework I wonder if you could use kUTTypeItem since it is the base type - indeed Apple describe it as 'the base type for most things'? I'd also perhaps try kUTTypeContent as that specifically mentions pasteboard data.

**EDIT**

It looks as if others are having the same problem - see the [previous thread here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9164278/storing-nsarray-in-uipasteboard) and note the answer about using NSPropertyListSerialization which whilst a bit of a pain, might allow you to get your date object back as a plist.

Comment: None of these work. I end up getting NSData objects returned from the pasteboard.

Comment: Even when using valueForPasteboardType rather than dataForPasteboardtype?