# nsnumber into uipasteboard

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsnumber, uipasteboard

I'd like to copy a float into the pasteboard, but the important thing is the value, as I want to paste it later in numbers, as a number.

Tried with :

```
[pasteboard setValue:SomeNSNumberWhereIStoredTheFloat forPasteboardType:@"NSNumber"];
```

With that, it got nothing to paste, and with `pasteboard.string = numberInStringValue`, it pastes the number as a series of characters, in what I'm not interested.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

The "type" of pasteboard data is not the name of a class, it's a [Uniform Type Identifier](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/understanding_utis/understand_utis_intro/understand_utis_intro.html) (UTI, or just UT if you remember what else UTI stands for.) In this case, your data does not have an associated UTI (numbers are abstract concepts, not data formats.) You'll have to figure out the best way to store that number and retrieve it.

I think in this case, formatting the number into a string will suffice:

```
NSString *numString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", theFloatValue];
pasteboard.string = numString;
```

And later, when getting it back:

```
float theFloatValue2 = [pasteboard.string doubleValue];
```

This does not take into account checking for `nil` or other error handling.

If you need very high precision, you may need to investigate an `NSData`-based storage technique.

Comment: It's what I tried, but I'd need to paste the number into a numbers sheet, treating it as a number. That's whay pasteboard.string doesn't work for me, I can't get it back later. 

Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

You can store an `NSNumber` directly. You can used the following methods from the API

> **setValue:forPasteboardType:**
>
> Use this method to put an object on the pasteboard that is a standard property-list object that is an object of the NSString, NSArray, NSDictionary, NSDate, NSNumber, or NSURL class.
>
> **valueForPasteboardType:**
>
> This method attempts to return an object that is of a class type appropriate to the representation type, which typically is a UTI. For example, if the representation type is kUTTypePlainText (public.plain-text), the method returns an NSString object. If the method cannot determine the class type from the representation type, it returns the object as a generic property-list object. Property-list objects include NSString, NSArray, NSDictionary, NSDate, or NSNumber objects, with NSURL objects also as a possibility. If the method cannot decode the value as a property-list object, it returns the pasteboard item as an NSData object.

The real problem comes in finding the correct UTI so the class will automatically give you back an `NSNumber` and not give you back an `NSData` object instead.

To make matters worse, the code doest not appear to work as the advertised by the documentation. I've heard from several people the method will always return you `NSData`. You can find an example (and a workaround) of such issue in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9164278/storing-nsarray-in-uipasteboard).

Answer (score 0):

You can store your float value as NSNumber.
But NSNumber is not stored in UIPasteboard correctly although docs states it does (bug?).

To keep NSNumber in UIPasteboard you should archive NSNumber to NSData, and to retrieve NSNumber from UIPasteboard you should unarchive NSData back to NSNumber.

```
// adding data to pasteboard
NSNumber *number = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:floatValue]; // store your value here
NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:number]; // archive NSNumber to NSData
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:data, @"yourKey",nil];
[[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard] addItems:[NSArray arrayWithObject:dict]];

// retrieving data
NSData *data = [dict valueForKey:@"yourKey"]; // here dict is properly obtained NSDictionary of pasteboard object
NSNumber *number = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data]; // unarchive NSData to NSNumber
```